# How do you partition when installing ubuntu 14.04 as sole OS?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I have a 2008 notebook, Acer Aspire 4930, with 250 GB HDD and 2 GB RAM.

I'm planning to use all the HDD for installing Ubuntu as a single OS in my notebook, but I don't understand how much should I allocate disk space on partition and where to allocate?
For file system, swap, temp, etc

I want to make as maximum my notebook can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best is just to install clean Ubuntu by choosing "Erase everything and install Ubuntu" in the installation process. It will create all the required partitions and do everything for you.

But anyway, if you want to create the partitions manually just check this out (Fully explained with photos): [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)
Or check this out: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace

According to your hdd size:

```
/home 180gb
/usr 10gb
/var 2gb
/lib 5gb
/swap ~amount of RAM (2gb in your case),
/tmp equal to swap or less
etc......
```

Comment: Default install is just /(root) and swap. And for a new user that is fine. But with new TB sized drives that makes a very large root and then smaller / of 20 or 25GB and separate /home for rest of space makes more sense. Only a few very old BIOS or BIOS not using ACHI but using IDE(not recommended) may need the /boot partition.

Comment: It's not always true. For example, I do have a laptop with ssd + 2xhdd (HP from 2013). It doesn't really able to find grub boot if /boot does not exists in the primary hdd (it is not possible to change boot order for hard drives in this bios). Also, I don't see any advantage for creating partitions for home etc.

Comment: Also some older Dell and maybe others have DVD that can become hard drive in a caddy. Those systems often do not boot from second drive. But most systems can boot from any drive if they support more than one drive. I generally agree that /home is not required, but for very large drives you do not want a 1 or 2TB / (root). For new users creating data partitions, which I use and suggest for users that understand partitions better may be a bit complex. Then /home may be a better choice as ownership & permissions are automatically created.

Comment: I just read your link, for /var and /temp, its written should be more than 5 GB, could you please tell me the specific size of /var and /temp?

Comment: Check this out: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace

Comment: tmp will not be larger than your swap space as a rule, so size this to match /swap. /var should be 2gb.

Comment: I've read an article that put swap twice amount of RAM, is that okay? Or just stay with 2 GB?

Comment: not twice ! the exact amount of RAM. if you have 2gb RAM, than swap should be also 2gb. Personally, I have 16gb of swap (I have 16gb RAM)

Comment: But still, for your computer specification, I would just use the default installation settings - "Erase and install". It will create swap and root. It's fine. I think you are wasting time. :) If this post was helpful, don't forget to make +1. Thanks.

Comment: Many thanks for your time to answer my questions :) I'm not wasting my time as I still learning and your answer does help me :) I'm sorry I coudn't give you +1 because I just sign up for this forum and don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: Sure. Anytime! :)